# Print correlation coefficient on scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation, scatter-plot

I would like to print the correlation coefficient on scatter plot. How can I achieve with ggplot2. My code is shown below

```
df = read.csv ("/home/miya/Desktop/data.csv")
p <- ggplot(df, aes(male,female,label=names)) + xlim(0,2) + ylim(0,2) + xlab("x axis") +
  ylab("y axis") + geom_point(colour = "red", size = 3) + geom_smooth(method=lm, fullrange=TRUE) + geom_text(hjust=-1,vjust=1)
```

data.csv

```
names   male    female
aa  1.43    1.3
kk  1.24    1.05
cc  1.04    0.94
dd  0.9     1.01
nn  0.93    1.17
mm  1.03    1.22
hh  1.12    1
gg  0.69    0.78
tt  0.92    1.04
```

Comment: Add this to your plot: `annotate(x=1.5, y=1.5, label=round(cor(df$male, df$female),2), geom="text").` Adjust x and y values depending on where you want it located on the plot.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I would like to print R=0.67 and also need to increase the font size. How is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For one-off additions like this, use `annotate`. In your case:

```
annotate(x=1.5, y=1.5, 
         label=paste("R = ", round(cor(df$male, df$female),2)), 
         geom="text", size=5)
```

Adjust x and y values depending on where you want it located on the plot. To change the font size, use the `size` argument, as shown above.